# How to count the frequency of values in a list with a condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working on a formula to populate a table which counts the frequency of userId values in column A per Month in column B.

So in the example below in 02/17 two users logged in once and in 03/17 three users logged in once, one logged in twice and one three times:

[image: table example]

I've tried using a combination of SUM and FREQUENCY but without success:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A10=B1,IF(PA1:A10<>"",MATCH(A1:A10,A1:A10,0))), ROW(A1:A10)-ROW(B1)+1),=1))
```

All help much appreciated!

Comment: Must be missing something here as it seems like countifs() would be enough...

Answer (score 0):

The formula needs to be corrected:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$11=$E2,IF($A$2:$A$11<>"",MATCH($A$2:$A$11,$A$2:$A$11,0))),ROW($A$2:$A$11)-ROW($A$2)+1)=F$1,1,0))
```

$A$2:$A$11 is the userid values (column under userid)
$B$2:$B$11 is the Months values (column under Months)
F$1 is the first 1 the column after Login Frequency
G$1 is 2
H$1 is 3...
Write the formula in F2 (E2 is the first month 02/17)
array formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> only and drag it in the same row and down it will change automatically to correspond 1,2,3,4